# ASP.NET 5 app hosted on Ubuntu won't access Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

ASP.NET 5 app works normally on IIS and allows adding anything to database on Azure SQL Server. With same connection string, while hosted on Ubuntu , it seams it can't access database. No exception is thrown, but my table with data (that should be fetched) from database is now empty.And I can't create new row.

Even with KRE, is it possible to access Azure Sql database from ASP.NET vNext app hosted on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to [Jsinh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376196/jsinh). It's `Encrypt` that caused me most of the problem, so I needed to set it to `false`, also, I needed to add `Trusted_Connection=False` in my connectionString in config.json. Thanks, Jsinh

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long shot, but make sure you double check that the public IP address of your Ubuntu server is allowed through the SQL Azure firewall.

Comment: I checked with person responsible for the Azure, both vm and database, when I started using Azure sql db. If we exclude that, I thought kre-mono would do the same thing as IIS and allow me to fetch data.